# How do I install the PS3 OS on a new HDD? 

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

My HDD is starting to make noise and I think it's time for me to change it. I have the old 60Gb PS3.

I was wondering the PS3 installs it's OS. Do I just have to switch the HDD and let the PS3 install it by itself? I don't think so. Does the option "Restore PS3 System" reinstall the OS on the hard drive?

What do I have to do to install the OS on the new HDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PS3's OS is not stored on the HDD, but the internal flash memory of the PS3. So switching a HDD will not do anything to the OS. So nothing is needed to be done, to get the PS3 up and running, after a HDD switch.

The HDD only stores, Media files, save games, DLC etc.

[Related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14860/where-does-the-ps3-store-user-accounts/15019#15019)

Comment: So you're telling me just to put the formated new drive and it will install.... Sounds too easy no ?

Comment: That's how easy it is. The OS is simply not running or being stored on the HDD.

Comment: Wrong, the Ps3 OS is stored on the HDD internally, and you can Visit the Sony Support site ON how to do this Via a Usb Stick.

Answer (score 0):

The "Restore PS3 System" option will delete everything from the hard drive and return all settings to their defaults.